# Getting XML Node

Tags: xml, scala

Given:

```
$scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_51).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val ns = <foo><bar><baz/>Text</bar><bin/></foo>
ns: scala.xml.Elem = <foo><bar><baz/>Text</bar><bin/></foo>
```

Why doesn't `ns \ "foo"` return the first `<foo>` node?

```
scala> ns \ "foo"
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<foo>` is the `Elem` you are calling the `\` method on. It is not contained within itself.

```
scala> val ns = <outer><foo><bar><baz/>Text</bar><bin/></foo></outer>
ns: scala.xml.Elem = <outer><foo><bar><baz/>Text</bar><bin/></foo></outer>

scala> ns \ "foo"
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<foo><bar><baz/>Text</bar><bin/></foo>)
```